# how to hide sequence of rows where value is not equal to 1,31,61,91 etc

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to hide all the rows other that rows having vales 1,31,61,91,121 etc

My row values are sorted and incrementing from 1 to 29160

Comment: You seem to be describing the sequence `30n+1` for `n` a natural number, so all `x` where `MOD(x-1,30) = 0`.

Comment: I dont know how to make VB code for it, Can you help me on this

Comment: It's an Excel formula: `MOD(A1-1,30) = 0` is `TRUE` if the value is `30n+1`, `FALSE` otherwise. Put it in a separate column, turn on table filtering and filter out all rows with `TRUE` -- no code necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help,   But I didnt clearly understand the way we need to write formula

Comment: I believe what Jeroen means is for you to write something like =IF(MOD(ROW(C1)-1;30)=0;"do not hide";"hide") and then apply a filter. Where C1 can be any cell on row 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code, as I miss interpreted your question (you want except). For very large data set the workbook might be slow to apply filtering due to re-calculations of worksheet. This VBA code hides all columns and then show every 30th row and is hopefully easy to modify for your purpose.

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub Hide_Every_nth_Row()
Dim n As Integer

Range("1:29160").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Hide all rows from row 1 to 29160

For n = 1 To 29160 Step 30 'start from row 1 and loop to row 29160. After every loop it jump 30 rows.
Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Show the nth Row set as "Step". It check the nth row and Column A (A = 1), but since you show the whole row, the column doesn't matter :)
Next n
End Sub
```

`n = 1`: Which row to start from.

`To 29160`: Which your end row is.

`Step 30`: How many step to jump every time it loops, starts from the "`n`"th value.

`EntireRow.Hidden = False`: To show row. Set this as `True` to hide every row.

Comment: I need 1, 31,61,91 etc

Comment: I guess you have a Header at first row, so your data starts at row 2. If that's the case, just use: `For n = 2 To 29160 Step 30` and it should work.